# FosUserBundle Return json when on login action via Ajax Http Post

Tags: ajax, symfony, fosuserbundle

When I perform a login via FosUserBundle on my Symfony3 project I want to return an Ajax response instead of the html of the3 lgoin form.

As fas I searched I found that there is a `fos_user_security_check` that uses the `FOSUserBundle:Security:check` that checks if the user is loged in or not but I could not find either the source code of controller that performs the login or any sort of custom trigger in order to do that.

I also looked into: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html but I cannot find a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is that Symfony's build-in authentication handler performs a redirect after a successful login or redirects back to the login form on failure. To handle AJAX logins you have to write your own authentication handler. This article explains it:

http://www.webtipblog.com/adding-an-ajax-login-form-to-a-symfony-project/